# enabling SSLv2/3 support in nodejs

Tags: node.js, ssl, openssl

I'm aware of the fact that SSLv2/3 is disabled because of vulnerability, in older version (0.10.33) --enable-ssl2 helps to enable SSLv2/3

in newer version of nodejs --enable-ssl2 or --enable-ssl3 is not working
and for experiment purpose i just want to enable SSLv3 in version nodejs 8+, can anyone help?

```
r=require('request');

r.get(
    {"url":"https://play.tech-vault.com/",
    "rejectUnauthorized":false,
    secureProtocol: 'SSLv3_method',
    secureOptions: require('constants').SSL_OP_DONT_INSERT_EMPTY_FRAGMENTS
},function(err, res, body) {
        console.log(err)
        console.log(body);
        console.log(res);
    }
)
```

Comment: support for sslv2 is removed in the newer versions of node js. Which version of nodejs are you working on?  Any error?